# How to remove records with their count per group below a threshold?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here's the DataFrame:

```
id | sector     | balance
---------------------------
1  | restaurant | 20000
2  | restaurant | 20000
3  | auto       | 10000
4  | auto       | 10000
5  | auto       | 10000
```

How to find the count of each `sector` type and remove the records with `sector` type count below a specific `LIMIT`?

The following:

```
dataFrame.groupBy(columnName).count()
```

gives me the number of times a value appears in that column.

How to do it in Spark and Scala using DataFrame API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it is the best way. But this worked for me.

```scala
def getRecordsWithColumnFrequnecyLessThanLimit(dataFrame: DataFrame, columnName: String, limit: Integer): DataFrame = {
    val g = dataFrame.groupBy(columnName)
                     .count()
                     .filter("count<" + limit)
                     .select(columnName)
                     .rdd
                     .map(r => r(0)).collect()
    dataFrame.filter(dataFrame(columnName) isin  (g:_*))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Window to do so.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
yourDf.withColumn("count", count("*")
      .over(Window.partitionBy($"colName")))
      .where($"count">2)
//    .drop($"count") // if you don't want to keep count column
      .show()
```

For your given dataframe

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
dataFrame.withColumn("count", count("*")
         .over(Window.partitionBy($"sector")))
         .where($"count">2)
         .show()
```

You should see results like this:

```
id | sector     | balance | count
------------------------------
3  | auto       | 10000   | 3
4  | auto       | 10000   | 3
5  | auto       | 10000   | 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a dataframe you can use SQL query like

```
select sector, count(1)
from TABLE
group by sector
having count(1) >= LIMIT
```